# Row rendering in Qooxdoo

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I am trying to display rows of my tables in different colors .
Please help me to achieve this. Please provide sample code to do same.
Thanks.

Regards,
vyankatesh

Answer (score 2):

Vyankatesh,

you probably saw the answers on the [qooxdoo mailing list](http://n2.nabble.com/Rendering-rows-of-table-in-different-colors-tp4865513p4865513.html).

To sum it up here: You either create your own [RowRenderer](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.table.IRowRenderer) and set it via qx.ui.table.Table.[setDataRowRenderer()](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.table.Table~setDataRowRenderer). Or you set up a conditional [CellRenderer](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Conditional) and set it via qx.ui.table.Table.getTableColumnModel().[setDataCellRenderer()](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.table.columnmodel.Basic~setDataCellRenderer). (There might be a unified way to do either through the Table or the TableModel, but I'm not aware of it).